# Shading glitch appearing on faces unsure why

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

so I just had this issue appear on my mesh seemingly out of nowhere and I'm unsure why. Last thing I recall doing before this problem occurred was turning the shading to smooth instead of flat and I came back to this problem. Its making the same effect when you have two faces on top of each other in the same location. I already tried dissolving faces and merging vertices to no avail. Any help?
[image]

Comment: It's just a guess. If you don't have overlapping faces, try to check this out: Object Data Properties > Normals and check Auto Smooth.

Comment: Have you tried selecting one of the faces where it shows and hide that face, like looking under the hood. To me it seems that there is some geometry hiding, as for example the seam going under the arm is vanishing inside the face that is lowest on the right side from the arm.